# Manipulate post json in PHP

Tags: php, json, post

I am posting json data from one php file to another. When I try to access different parts of the json in the final php file, I am getting "Illegal string offset" warnings.

How can I access different parts of posted json data?

Here is my json:

```
{
    "state": {
        "date":"2020-05-14 09:16:01",
        "total_cases":"35,903",
        "diff_total_cases":"1,091",
        "confirmed_deaths":"1,748",
        "diff_confirmed_deaths":"54",
        "neg_tests":"142,551",
        "total_tests":"178,454",
        "curr_hospitalized":"1,538",
        "diff_hospitalized":"-12",
        "total_recovered":"2,569",
        "diff_total_recovered":"113",
        "active":"31,586"
    },
    "counties":[array],
    "zipcodes": [array]
}
```

Full json that is returned can be viewed here: https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb49c080

When I write the following, the entire json is returned:

```
<?php
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    print_r($json);
?>
```

But when I try to access any part of the data, nothing is returned. This produces an "Illegal string offset" warning:

```
<?php
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $state_date = $json["state"]["date"];
    print_r($state_date);
?>
```

Comment: Your object keys aren't quoted, so that's not valid JSON. The full text of your error message reads "Illegal string offset on NULL", doesn't it? The answer to your next question is "Don't try to write a custom decoder for broken input, fix the thing that's generating broken data."

Comment: I also think `counties: [array]` means the data isn't encoded properly.

Comment: @Sammitch sorry for the misinformation. That was my browser ext formatting the json. I have reposted the raw json returned without formatting. The two errors I get are: Warning: Illegal string offset 'state', and Warning: Illegal string offset 'date'

Comment: @NigelRen I am just indicating that there are two arrays that are returned. They are very large arrays of objects.

Comment: Do you have both sets of code in the same script? You can only read from `php://input` once.

Comment: @Barmar No I do not. I am just demonstrating the differences in the output for each.

Comment: Put the `print_r()` right before the `$state_date` assignment, what do you see then?

Comment: @Barmar "Warning: print_r() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given." If I do print_r($json), the full json is returned as expected.

Comment: Then the JSON must not be as you showed, because your code should work.

Comment: @Barmar full json that is returned is posted here: https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb49c080. The json appears to be formatted properly and this is why I am posting the message for help. Thank you!

Comment: What does `echo gettype($json);` show?

Comment: @Barmar string!

Comment: That's the problem For some reason the data is encoded twice, so you need `$json = json_decode(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")), true);`

Comment: What does print_r( file_get_contents("php://input") ) output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$json = json_decode(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")), true);` did the trick!